# Kendo MVC Grid , Hide .Filterable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo MVC Grid and am using some if statements to control some filters depending on a users access level I want the user not to be able to filter records themselves so I removed .Filterable , which works great all the filters I apply are there but the user can not change them. 
Now the Admins have requested a feature so they can see all records ( all ready done) but they want to filter too. So my question is how can I make .Filterable appear only when an Admin logs in. An example of who I`m doing the Filters is below

```
.Filterable() // need to only show userLevel == Admin //
.ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Sort(sort => sort.Add("ID").Descending())
.Filter (filters => {
    if (ViewBag.userLevel == "Manager")
    {
        filters.Add(a => a.ManagersName).IsEqualTo(ViewBag.manager);
        filters.Add(a => a.Status).IsEqualTo("New Application");
    }
    if (ViewBag.userLevel == "Job Evaluations")
    {
        filters.Add(a => a.Stage).IsEqualTo("Job Evaluation");
        filters.Add(a => a.Status).IsEqualTo("New Application");
    }
    if (ViewBag.userLevel == "Finance")
    {
        filters.Add(a => a.Stage).IsEqualTo("Finance");
        filters.Add(a => a.Status).IsEqualTo("New Application");
    }
    if (ViewBag.userLevel == "Head of Service")
    {
        filters.Add(a => a.Stage).IsEqualTo("Head of Service");
        filters.Add(b => b.HeadOfService).IsEqualTo(ViewBag.manager);
        filters.Add(a => a.Status).IsEqualTo("New Application");
    }
    if (ViewBag.userLevel == "Director")
    {
        filters.Add(a => a.Stage).IsEqualTo("Director");
        //need director name or delegate
        filters.Add(a => a.Status).IsEqualTo("New Application");
    }
    if (ViewBag.userLevel == "Chief Executive")
    {
        filters.Add(a => a.Stage).IsEqualTo("Chief Executive");
        //need CE or Delegate
        filters.Add(a => a.Status).IsEqualTo("New Application");
    }
    if (ViewBag.userLevel == "Admin")
    {

    }


})
```

Comment: A not very clean implementation would be to have a separate partial view for each user role and define the filters in that.  It would not be very efficient but if this way does not work you can always resort to that, especially if you are being forced to get this feature out.

Comment: I`ve cleaned it up to use partials, just didn`t think of it. Everyone can have the view they like :)

Answer (score 0):

Used partial views to control what a user sees.